# Facebook sharing is only visible to my profile, JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-graph-api

So far into the development stage of my website I have successfully integrated a Facebook login system, a like system for required pages and I am now working on sharing content publicly from users. In this case the content being shared is a link to a product for sale, and the option of a caption, paragraph etc with it. More so the post is on my Facebook wall but it is not available for other users to view. In an attempt to find a solution I have found nothing but I have suspicions as to the configuration and not the code. Im using the JavaScript SDK.

> The following code prints a share button for a variable product id.

```
 <div style="margin-left: 15px" class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://my-website/product/<?php echo $product['id']?>" data-layout="button_count"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the application associated to your website on the the facebook developper page.

If the application is not public, the content you share throught it is only visible to the admins of the page or the app developper.

You can check the status here : 
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{yourappid}/review-status/

Depending you what permissions you ask, the app might need to go through the review process which takes like 2 or 3 days I think.

It seems that you could also create test users for you app, which would be friends with each others to test what the others can see, but I have never done it myself, so it is just a guess.